# Reason to normalize individual's fitness when using roulette-wheel selection

Tags: genetic-algorithm, genetic-programming

As I can read examples of roulette-wheel selection there is always checked 
normalized individual's fitness against a uniform random value.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_(genetic_algorithm)

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fitness_proportionate_selection

Is there any pros/cons to don't use the normalized value so the last part of the alghoritm
could look like (pseudo code):

```
while (candidates.length < target_size) {
    var random = random() * fitness_sum; // vs: random()
    for (items as item) {
        if (item.fitness > random) {//vs: item.fitness/fitness_sum > random
            candidates.push(population[i]);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no practical reason. However, there is a theoretical reason, that is, if you normalize the fitnesses you get probabilities instead of some arbitrary numbers and you can treat it like probability (it sums up to one, etc.).